# How can I update the color_map of a tinymce editor

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

How can I update the color_map of a tinymce editor after it has been initialized ?

I cannot find a method for this purpose in the API documentation.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the editor is initialized that value is read from the configuration - there is currently no API or other means to modify the color map once it has been loaded.  You can submit a feature request in the TinyMCE issue tracker:

https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/new/choose

Answer (score 1):

The first answer isnt true - at least for v6, you can update the color map after initialization. I am doing it with in a function, here are the contents of the function:

```
var editors = tinymce.get();
if (!editors || !editors.length) {
    console.warn('tinyMce sendColorPalette - no editors found');
}
editors.forEach(function (editor) {
    editor.options.set('color_map', ['000000', 'Black', 'FFFFFF', 'White']);
```